# Use of the word 'where'

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, interrogatives

What's the subtle difference between the sentences ' where is he going ?' and 'He is going where'

Comment: The first is a normal question. The second, if used as a question, would express surprise at what the speaker had just been told of someone's destination - "He's going _where_?". Otherwise it isn't a complete sentence.

Comment: Any reason why this is not entered as an answer? It is, after all, the only usage where one would use that second form.

Comment: What type of sentence would you classify it into

Answer (score 2):

The first is a normal question.

The second, if used as a question, would express surprise at what the speaker had just been told of someone's destination - "He's going *where*?". Otherwise it isn't a complete sentence. It could be continued "He is going where his enemies can't find him."

Comment: What type of sentence would you classify the second sentence . If assertive then why ?

Comment: As a complete sentence, it's an incredulous question, as I explained.